# Linear space and transformation such $X = Y + im(F)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$X$ is linear space, $\dim X < \infty$, $Y \subset X$ is linear subspace and $X = Y + \operatorname{im}(F)$ for some linear transformation $F \in L(Y,X)$. Prove that $\dim X \le 2 \cdot \dim Y$ and there is equality iff $F$ is monomorphism and $Y \cap \operatorname{im}(F) = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- prove $\dim(X) \le \dim(Y) + \dim (\text{im}(F))$ (with equality if and only if $Y \cap \text{im}(F)=\{0\}$)
- prove $\dim (\text{im}(F)) \le \dim(Y)$ (with equality if and only if $F$ is a monomorphism)